# Jenkins Docker plugin is not showing the Tag-on-completion checkbox

Tags: checkbox, jenkins, docker, boot2docker, dockerpy

I am using the Jenkins Docker Plugin.

I am supposed to see the `Tag-on-completion` checkbox with so that the images will be retained in docker.

Reference: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

However in my Jenkins, do not see the `Tag-on-completion` checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiki document is outdated, the Tag-on-compete checkbox is moved into job.

The checkbox name is now called

```
Commit on successful build [x]
Clean local images []
```

See source code [config.jelly](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerJobProperty/config.jelly)